# Date Difference in minutes SP Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a SharePoint Calculated column that is supposed to calculate the difference in hours and minutes between two dates.

This is the expression I am using for that:

```
=TEXT([IN/OUT Time]-[Staging Time],"hh:mm:ss")
```

The only thing is, if the time is over 24 hours it shows up as if it is in days.

Example: if the difference is 24 hours and 7 minutes, the result of the above expression shows "00:07:00".

I want it to show: "24:01:00".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are formatting the result to show only the time value, so what do you expect?

In Excel, you can use the [] brackets to show values greater than 24 hours in the hour part. Not sure it works in SharePoint, but you can try.

"[hh]:mm:ss"

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this, so I appreciate you pointing that out, even though it was obvious to you.